# How can I display range of objects using django pagination?

Tags: python, django, dajaxice

I am making an AJAX pagination template displaying a 5x5 [Dota 2](http://blog.dota2.com/) player item backpack grid (see screenshot -- it is the one made by steam).

[image: Dota 2 player backpack]

The thing is, a page can have empty slots.

The following code will not handle it. If the second slot is empty (no `Item` having a `slot_nb` field with value `2`), the `Item` object with a `slot_nb` of value `25` will be displayed on the first page when it should be displayed on the second one (slot_nb index starts at `0`)

```
def get_pagination_page(page=1):
    items = Items.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(items, 25) # 25 items per page
    try:
        page = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return items
```

What I basically want is for each page to render `Item.objects.filter(slot_nb=range(((page_nb*25)-25)), ((page_nb*25)-1))` (`page_nb` starts at 1)

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Paginator actually perform slicing operation.

```
# paginator.py
...
return Page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

So all you have to do is make `Items` ordering by `slot_nb`

```
items = Items.objects.all().order_by('slot_nb')
```